# Column in table is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I am storing employee details. I want to alter the table and set one of the column `emp_code` as primary key. Its datatype is `nvarchar(max)`, but I am not able to set it as primary key.

I run the following query :

```
ALTER TABLE user_master
ADD PRIMARY KEY (emp_code)
```

but it gives me an error :

> *Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1*
>   *Column `emp_code` in table `user_master` is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.*
>   *Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1*
>   *Could not create constraint. See previous errors.*

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Blob column can not be used for indexing, they need to be of the fixed size.

Comment: Does it need to be MAX? SQL Server is telling you that you can't have that as a key type. Why not just shorten it to something useful?

Comment: Your emp_code column is too wide:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863993/is-of-a-type-that-is-invalid-for-use-as-a-key-column-in-an-index

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An index's key cannot exceed a total size of 900 bytes. Change the data type to `NVARCHAR(450)`. If that is not suitable, use a surrogate key (typically an `IDENTITY` column).

Comment: wild guess of the required size ;), what if requires all 2 GB of it.

Comment: @010001100110000101110010011010 It's the largest possible size for a primary key of `NVARCHAR(x)`.

Comment: Great !! size was the issue. I set it to 450, (which is max) and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Very true size limitation is 900 bytes for the keys.

Comment: Also: even if you **technically** can make a `NVARCHAR(450)` column your primary key - if you happen to also make that your **clustering key** on that table - you'll have **horribly bad** performance all around. All your nonclustered indices will be huge and inefficient, and your queries will need to read a lot more pages than actually necessary. A **good clustering key** should be **NARROW** - heck, I'm even saying 16 byte for a GUID is too much! Don't use overly large and variable length clustering keys!

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `varchar(max)`.  It isn't designed to store primary keys.

Find out what the longest employee code, and create a sized nvarchar that covers your longest case.

e.g. longest employee code is 70 characters, try:-

```
nvarchar(100)
```

...just to cover yourself.

Comment: `NVARCHAR(100)` might be better, considering it's `NVARCHAR` now.

Comment: Amended in line with ta's comments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct.Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index `PK__bookmark__2DFA2B0E164452B1` has maximum length of 2000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
not use of `varchar(max)`