# Convert varchar(max) to varchar(N)

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have many user-defined-scalar-functions which return `varchar(max)` as a result. As a consequence the whole column is varchar(max) even if it consists of only few character strings. I need to convert those `varchar(max)` into `varchar(N)` to use them as index. I have to do this because indexes are not allowed on `varchar(max)`.

Is there an easy and fast way to convert all `varchar(max)` columns in a table to `varchar(N)` where N is the actual used max length of the variable? Can you please advice how to loop through all the `varchar(max)` columns in a table with the code below. The most desirably would be a procedure with the name of a table as a parameter.

```
declare @SQL varchar(max);
declare @N varchar(max); 
set @N = (SELECT max(len([MyColumn])) FROM [dbo].[MyTable])
set @SQL='ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [MyColumn] VARCHAR (' + @N +')'

--select @SQL
exec (@SQL)
```

**Update.** Alternatively, is there a way to force scalar UDF to return varchar(N) where N would be dynamically adjusted according to the length of the returned string?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It makes very little difference to the size of the data or performance.

Comment: You say UDF but you also say something about variables in a table. There is likely a language barrier there but I am a bit confused. Are you trying to modify all your tables that have a datatype of varchar(max)? Do you really think that is a good idea? Do all the applications and procedures not allow for a longer value than the current longest value? This just seems to be fraught with serious challenges.

Comment: What if you suceeeded, and then tried to add a record with a longer value?

Comment: @DanBracuk then I will be informed that something is wrong with the results because the length of my variables is fixed. That is why I want it. Imagine that you know that you should get a variable with length of 6, and you get prompt about truncation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Another good reason for doing it is that you cannot have indexes on variables varchar(max) http://stackoverflow.com/a/2864109/1903793

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin . . . That is a good point, but it argues for setting all the columns to a maximum length of 900 or so, not to a custom length.

Comment: I have a task to do the exact same thing.  Previous developers set all varchar columns to varchar(max) in a particular db.  My task is to create a script, or scripts, to alter the varchar(max) columns to a reasonable length for given column, based upon maximum length of data per column (I may add 10%).  Of course, corresponding maxlen's will need to be added to textboxes and such in the application, so that we can avoid truncation upon update / insert.  I will post whatever I discover / create / google that I think is a workable solution.