# Error when attempting to apply Migration script 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema to a fresh Sql Azure Database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v1.1.0 on a default configuration of the asp.net core MVC template.

Added FacebookAuthentication and deployed it to Azure with Environment Variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to Development so that i can see error messages.

After attempting to Login using facebook and am returned to the website I am shown the below error

[image]

But when I attempt to Apply the Migration script i get the following Error

SqlException: Column 'NormalizedName' in table 'AspNetRoles' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Comment: do you have length restriction on `NormalisedName` column?

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2864109/809357

Comment: I have not changed anything! using the default model that's in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0

Comment: But is there a length restriction on the field? Because that is what the SQL error saying - the field can be too long to be an index.