# Entity Framework Core: Column 'Id' in table 'Users' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

It works under SQLite

DbContext.cs

```
public class DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

User.cs

```
public class User : OAuthUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

OAuthUser.cs

```
public class OAuthUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then I executed `Add-Migration` and `Database-Update`. It should be updated to the SQLServer on my machine But it logged this error:

> Column 'Id' in table 'Users' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I want `Id` in `OAuthUser.cs` as the primary key, but there's an error

Comment: A Key column is a Primary Key in the SQL Database.  So the type has to match and the type needs a Hash method.  Normal c# classes line int or string have built in Hash methods.  In the SQL Database did you check the type that is used for the key?

Comment: Why `DbSet<User>` if you want make it work for `OrganizationUser`?

Comment: Now that you have `User` in database. But what is the relationship between `User` and your `OrganizationUser` and `OAuthUser`? Why don't you show us the source code of the `User`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It needs to remove all migrations when changing a database service.

Comment: Deleted the migrations folder and worked just perfectly

Comment: Remove-Database till all migrations gone

Answer (score 5):

The error is showing due to the lack of `StringLength` specification. In case of `string` primary key you have to specify the length because primary key in sql server is an unique-indexed key.

If you want the `Id` column to be primary of `string` type then you have to put `StringLength` on this column as follows:

```
public class OAuthUser
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    ...........
}
```

Or if you want `Id` column to be `auto-generated` primary key then it should be as follows:

```
public class OAuthUser
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    ...........
}
```

You choose of either of the two.

Comment: I don't think, that it is necessary requirement

Comment: @Anton The error is showing the due to the lack of `StringLength` specification. In case of string primary key you have to specify the length because primary key in sql server is an indexed key.

Comment: I have a lot of projects where I don't specify length of string key. It makes automatically. So in my opinion, there is a problem somewhere else. I can mistake.

Comment: @Anton Please read the error message. It  clearly saying that problem lies in the indexation.

Comment: @Anton Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863993/is-of-a-type-that-is-invalid-for-use-as-a-key-column-in-an-index

Comment: Thank. I clearly understand you. I just wanted to say that there is a possibility of having error somewhere else, because user code is not clear enough to make a decision. Anyway I hope your answer will help user

Comment: Why it can work with SQLite, but can't work with SQLServer?

Comment: Is the `StringLength` the max string length?

Comment: The link you are referring to is from 2010 (probably EF 1,2,3 or something), EF and EF Core evolved a lot from that time. Nowadays neither EF6 nor EF Core require specifying the max length explicitly, so @Anton brought up a valid point. You can try yourself (as soon as the `OrganizationUser` is the `User` from the error message) - EF Core for SqlServer by default assumes max length = 450 for string key properties.

Comment: It is still failed after I chose the first one. `Column 'Id' in table 'Users' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.`

Comment: @JebFeng: Different database system, different rules. SQL Server refuses string PKs without length because of how it implements its indexation (which is inherent to keys). Other database systems may handle this differently and thus not have an issue with it.

Comment: Works exactly in the case when Index annotation was added, migration added and DB update attempt failed. Removing the Index adding migration and trying with both Index and StringLength specified works well. Note this is for non EF core (pre-EF-Core).

Answer (score 3):

This normally happens when you try updating a database with migrations on a different database provider than the one it was generated for. For example if using an `sqlite database` when generating the migrations, do not update an `MSSQL database` with it. Instead, delete all the migrations and generate them afresh.